# Display "minutes ago" in android app

Tags: android, date-difference

I tried my best to do research and look for the tutorial, but still confused about it. My problem is, I want to display something like "minutes ago" based on create date and time I fetched from json data.

When I fetched the date and time from server I want to display it in livestatTimeAgo textview, but it show error because getTimeAgo method is in long format. So I used parseLong to change the data I fetched, but still got error. Can somebody give me hint on how to display long data to string value like this.

This is the error log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.baracode.eilsan, PID: 898
                                                                 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2017-08-25 09:20:54"
                                                                     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:443)
                                                                     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:485)
                                                                     at com.baracode.eilsan.livestat.adapter.LivestatAdapter.onBindViewHolder(LivestatAdapter.java:49)
                                                                     at com.baracode.eilsan.livestat.adapter.LivestatAdapter.onBindViewHolder(LivestatAdapter.java:29)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6400)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6433)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5377)
```

This is my code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.baracode.eilsan.R;
import com.baracode.eilsan.model.LiveFeed;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.Format;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Created by kille on 17/7/2017.
 */

public class LivestatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LivestatAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private final ArrayList<LiveFeed> livestatList;
    private LiveFeed liveFeed;




    public LivestatAdapter(ArrayList<LiveFeed> livestatList) {
        this.livestatList = livestatList;
    }

    @Override
    public LivestatAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_livestat, parent, false);
        return new LivestatAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        LiveFeed livestatModel = livestatList.get(position);
        holder.livestatTimeAgo.setText(getTimeAgo(Long.parseLong(livestatModel.createdAt)));
        holder.livestatOrganisationName.setText(livestatModel.beneficiaryName);
        holder.livestatMoneyDonated.setText(livestatModel.amount);
        holder.livestatDonorName.setText(livestatModel.donorName);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return livestatList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView livestatTimeAgo, livestatDonorName, livestatOrganisationName, livestatMoneyDonated;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            livestatTimeAgo = view.findViewById(R.id.livestat_time_ago);
            livestatOrganisationName = view.findViewById(R.id.livestat_organisation_name);
            livestatMoneyDonated = view.findViewById(R.id.livestat_money_donated);
            livestatDonorName = view.findViewById(R.id.livestat_donor_name);

        }
    }

//    private String ConvertTime(String time) {
//
//        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
//        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa MM-dd");
//        java.util.Date date = null;
//
//        try {
//            date = format.parse(time);
//        } catch (ParseException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
//
//        String convertedDate = format1.format(date);
//
//        return convertedDate;
//    }

    public static String getTimeAgo(long timestamp) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();//get your local time zone.
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm ss");
        sdf.setTimeZone(tz);//set time zone.
        String localTime = sdf.format(new Date(timestamp * 1000));
        Date date = new Date();
        try {
            date = sdf.parse(localTime);//get local date
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(date == null) {
            return null;
        }

        long time = date.getTime();

        Date curDate = currentDate();
        long now = curDate.getTime();
        if (time > now || time <= 0) {
            return null;
        }

        int timeDIM = getTimeDistanceInMinutes(time);

        String timeAgo = null;

        if (timeDIM == 0) {
            timeAgo = "less than a minute";
        } else if (timeDIM == 1) {
            return "1 minute";
        } else if (timeDIM >= 2 && timeDIM <= 44) {
            timeAgo = timeDIM + " minutes";
        } else if (timeDIM >= 45 && timeDIM <= 89) {
            timeAgo = "about an hour";
        } else if (timeDIM >= 90 && timeDIM <= 1439) {
            timeAgo = "about " + (Math.round(timeDIM / 60)) + " hours";
        } else if (timeDIM >= 1440 && timeDIM <= 2519) {
            timeAgo = "1 day";
        } else if (timeDIM >= 2520 && timeDIM <= 43199) {
            timeAgo = (Math.round(timeDIM / 1440)) + " days";
        } else if (timeDIM >= 43200 && timeDIM <= 86399) {
            timeAgo = "about a month";
        } else if (timeDIM >= 86400 && timeDIM <= 525599) {
            timeAgo = (Math.round(timeDIM / 43200)) + " months";
        } else if (timeDIM >= 525600 && timeDIM <= 655199) {
            timeAgo = "about a year";
        } else if (timeDIM >= 655200 && timeDIM <= 914399) {
            timeAgo = "over a year";
        } else if (timeDIM >= 914400 && timeDIM <= 1051199) {
            timeAgo = "almost 2 years";
        } else {
            timeAgo = "about " + (Math.round(timeDIM / 525600)) + " years";
        }

        return timeAgo + " ago";
    }

    public static Date currentDate() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        return calendar.getTime();
    }

    private static int getTimeDistanceInMinutes(long time) {
        long timeDistance = currentDate().getTime() - time;
        return Math.round((Math.abs(timeDistance) / 1000) / 60);
    }



}
```

here my livefeed class..

```
public class LiveFeed {

    @SerializedName("id")
    public String id = "";

    @SerializedName("ref_id")
    public String refId = "";

    @SerializedName("beneficiary_type")
    public String beneficiaryType = "";

    @SerializedName("beneficiary_name")
    public String beneficiaryName = "";

    @SerializedName("donor_name")
    public String donorName = "";

    @SerializedName("amount")
    public String amount = "";

    @SerializedName("description")
    public String description = "";

    @SerializedName("remark")
    public String remark = "";

    @SerializedName("status")
    public String status = "";

    @SerializedName("created_at")
    public String createdAt = "";


    @SerializedName("updated_at")
    public String updatedAt = "";

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRefId() {
        return refId;
    }

    public void setRefId(String refId) {
        this.refId = refId;
    }

    public String getBeneficiaryType() {
        return beneficiaryType;
    }

    public void setBeneficiaryType(String beneficiaryType) {
        this.beneficiaryType = beneficiaryType;
    }

    public String getBeneficiaryName() {
        return beneficiaryName;
    }

    public void setBeneficiaryName(String beneficiaryName) {
        this.beneficiaryName = beneficiaryName;
    }

    public String getDonorName() {
        return donorName;
    }

    public void setDonorName(String donorName) {
        this.donorName = donorName;
    }

    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getRemark() {
        return remark;
    }

    public void setRemark(String remark) {
        this.remark = remark;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

}
```

So this is the correct answer for my question..updated code on how to get the time..for anyone who want to refer !!! thank you

```
DateFormat getDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String fromDate = getDate.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
String endDate = livestatModel.updatedAt; //here my jsondataName

long diff = 0;
try {
    //Convert to Date
    Date startDate = getDate.parse(fromDate);
    Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    //Change to Calendar Date
    c1.setTime(startDate);

    //Convert to Date
    Date endDate2 = getDate.parse(endDate);
    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    //Change to Calendar Date
    c2.setTime(endDate2);

    //get Time in milli seconds
    long ms1 = c1.getTimeInMillis();
    long ms2 = c2.getTimeInMillis();
    //get difference in milli seconds
    diff = ms1 - ms2;

    if (diff < 0) {
        holder.livestatTimeAgo.setText(" 0 day " + " 0 hour " + " 0 minute " + " 0 sec " + "left");
    } else {
        int diffInDays = (int) (diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        int diffInHours = (int) ((diff / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
        int diffInMinutes = (int) ((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        int diffInSec = (int) ((diff / 1000) % 60);
        holder.livestatTimeAgo.setText(diffInDays + " days " + diffInHours + " hours " + diffInMinutes + " minutes " + diffInSec + " secs " + "Ago");
    }
}catch (Exception e){}
```

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2017-08-25 09:20:54"` which number should your date string represent?

Comment: i want it represent something like "1 minutes ago" in textview sir. My json date data in string format, so i use getTimeAgo method() to change it. but that method in long format. so now how to display it?. iwant to display it in string format.

Comment: I wasn't clear. Your error tells you that you're trying to convert a date string to a number. You want to get the difference between two dates. Which is what you should google for.

Comment: i want to convert my date currently in string datatype to long datatype before display...

Comment: You can't convert a NOT A NUMBER to a number. Is it clear, now?

Comment: tell me how to fix this?..please

Answer (score 1):

First convert your String to a calendar :

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
 cal.setTime(sdf.parse("2017-08-25 09:20:54"));
```

Then use

```
long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

and this should to the trick.

**EDIT**

This is a possible example of what you want to do. I don't know if the calculations are correct but is works.

```
 try{

 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 cal.setTime(sdf.parse("2017-08-25 09:20:54"));

  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
  long now = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
  long time = cal.getTimeInMillis();

  long diff = now - time;

  int seconds = (int) (diff / 1000) % 60 ;
  int minutes = (int) ((diff / (1000*60)) % 60);
  int hours   = (int) ((diff / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
  int days = (int) (diff / (1000*60*60*24));

  System.out.println(time + " " + now);
  System.out.println(hours + " hours ago");
  System.out.println(minutes + " minutes ago");
  System.out.println(seconds + " seconds ago");
  System.out.println(days + " days ago");


}catch(ParseException e){
     System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: i fetched the time from json...when i put it in setTime() it become error..

Comment: see my edition to the answer. It is just an example, you must do the calculations by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error in following line.

```
holder.livestatTimeAgo.setText(getTimeAgo(Long.parseLong(livestatModel.createdAt)));
```

And since the error is `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2017-08-25 09:20:54"` that pretty much means `livestatModel.createdAt` holds 
`2017-08-25 09:20:54` which is more of a String value and can't be parsed to Long as it comprises syntaxes like colon, hyphen and space.

**Update**

To convert your date String to long, you need to parse `livestatModel.createdAt` with a `SimpleDateFormat` (like you did in `getTimeAgo` method but with different format).

Here's how you can achieve this.

```
long createdAtLong = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(livestatModel.createdAt).getTime();

holder.livestatTimeAgo.setText(getTimeAgo(createdAtLong));
```

Comment: so sir.. how to fix this. I need to fetched the data without colon or what?...here my request api...

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: thank you sir... but where should i implement this...i need to  create another method or just put the long createdLong below onBindViewHolder method...

Comment: Above this line should do the job. `holder.livestatTimeAgo.setText(getTimeAgo(createdAtLong));`

Comment: when i implement this under onBindViewHolder it said i need to surround with try catch.  Then when i run the app it shown nothing..but no error

Comment: if i put above it...same also sir need to surround with try catch...

Comment: then the error like this.. java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.baracode.eilsan.model.LiveFeed.createdAt' on a null object reference